# How could I get a pointer to an already-deduced template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a template function and I want to use it with its template parameters been auto deduced.
It works well but now I need its `ptr` to be used in `std::bind`.

It's something like this:

```
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};

template<template<typename...> class TContainer, typename TR, typename... TEles>
void func(TContainer<TEles...> container, function<TR(HeadOf<TEles...>::type)> f)
{
    TContainer<TR> rst;
    for(auto it : container)
    {
        fill(rst, f(it));
    }
    return rst;
}

vector<A>      vec_A;  // type : vector<A, allocator<A>>
MyContainer<B> cont_B; // type : MyContainer<B, allovator<B>, Maybe_Sth_Else>  

// auto ptrFoo = func_ptr_of( func(vec_A, transA2B) );
// auto ptrBar = func_ptr_of( func(cont_B, transB2C) );

// auto contB2contC = std::bind(ptrBar, placeholder::_1, transB2C);
// contB2contC(cont_B);
```

Comment: I am fairly sure this is impossible and the best you can do is `&func<A, B>`.

Comment: @DanielH okay. what a pity.

Comment: `auto ptrFoo = &func<decltype((A{})), decltype((B{}))>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 In my case it may be a little more complicated that I can't use the way you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

But if you have a C++14 compiler, you can do something similar with a variadic lambda.

By example

```
A  a{};

auto fakeBondFunc = [&](auto ... as) { func(a, as...); };

fakeBondFunc(B{});
```

If you want fix a first `A` parameter and impose that the second is a `B` one, you can do it also in C++11 (no needs of variadic lambda)

```
A  a{};

auto fakeBondFunc = [&](B const & b) { func(a, b); };

fakeBondFunc(B{});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using ptr_t = void(*)(A, B);
    ptr_t ptrFoo = func<A, B>;
    std::function<void(B)> boundFunc = std::bind(ptrFoo, A{}, std::placeholders::_1);
    boundFunc(B{});
```

Comment: emm... In fact my template parameters are complete mess, so I try finding a way to deduce them automatically. But it seems impossible.